# Display equivalent of "MMM d, yyyy" in current culture info

Tags: c#, xamarin, localization, internationalization, globalization

I've perused the standard datetime formatters that C# offers, and I can't seem to find one that matches my "short date" requirement: "May 4, 2013". I know that I can do a custom format string to accomplish the goal:

```
myDateTimeOffset.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
```

However, this application may go to other countries. Is there a way to get the current culture's equivalent to a particular format string?

```
myDateTimeOffset.ToString("MMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

And have it adapt to an equivalent "short date" format in the foreign culture?

Comment: I think that is the point of the standard formats.  I am sure they thought hard about which format would map to 'general', 'long' etc

Comment: Other than the month names exactly how would you expect that format to be different based on culture?

Comment: @juharr The order, perhaps... `4 Mayo 2013`

Comment: @Seafish I don't know.  It seems less important when you use month names.  "Mayo 4" or "4 Mayo" isn't going to confuse someone the way "5 4" or "4 5" would.

Comment: Option 1: You can use shortdate and instruct the users to change their windows settings if they want another display format. Disadvantage: all applications will use this setting. Option 2: Make your format string configurable in config file or database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any default format option baked in that maches your specific requirement (`D` may come close). I've this overview in my bookmarks for more than 10 years now, and I find it still useful: http://samples.pdmlab.com/

Anyway, as your app may not be available for an infinite amount of languages, I think your best choice will be to use some kind of DateTime extension method and format depending on the actual language being used, if even necessary.

Comment: We're planning now on putting the appropriate date format strings into resx files which will then localized and the correct date format string will be pulled based on the CultureInfo.