# DateTime standard format for day, month and year

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any standard DateTime format for showing "[day] [month] [year]"?
I do not wish to use custom format strings, because it takes away the ability to have order of "day" and "month" depending on the country.
For example, for "en-us" it's "November 22", in France day is first, so it's "22 Novembre"

Just to display day and month like this, I know I can use "M" standard format string.

But how I can write "November 22, 2018" ?

Do I need to concatenate two strings like this:

`$"{dt.ToString("M")}, {dt.ToString("yyyy")}"`

Is there another way?

Comment: So what you want? _"Day Month, Year"_, or every country with its own format?

Comment: Every country with its own format

Comment: But just day month and year

Comment: What type is your project? WinForms, MVC, WPF..etc?

Comment: It's WPF, but it shouldn't matter I think, it's NET

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings doesn't seem to have a standard format for just Day Month and Year which is suprising

Comment: If it was web project, it would've been matter.

Comment: how come it would had mattered?

Comment: @DonBox: I'm unclear what you are asking. You have linked to the list of standard date time formats and you have confirmed that the format you want isn't in there. You have given a way of getting the output you want. So can you clarify what you want answers to cover? I can't think of what information you might be after that isn't on the documentation page you linked... Unless its just confirmation that its surprising that there isn't one for what you want in which case yes, I'd agree it is a bit strange.

Comment: So you think my question makes no sense and it's just obvious to say that who ever designed this API is .NET made a mistake by forgetting about it? And nobody has seen it but me? It's that simple?

Comment: I think your question makes sense but you have come up with a solution already which is the source of my confusion. Though having seen sellotapes answer it occurs to me that this might be something you were looking for (it uses custom date formats but in that context maybe you are in fact ok with that).

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for me as well. I personally think that your questions makes sense, but you need to formulate it better, with proper examples. For me it sounds like you want to get `MMMM dd, yyyy`, which is already answered.

Comment: .NET didn't forget about anything you've mentioned, there is always a way to do something, but is that a correct way? Maybe there is a different approach here. Why you want to show month name with text? Just show "dd/MM/yyyy", with current culture and everybody will be happy. Or create some check by yourself, and if current culture of machine fits one of your cases, show correct format, if no, some default format.

Comment: @SeM You are right. I will delete my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display equivalent of "MMM d, yyyy" in current culture info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577006/display-equivalent-of-mmm-d-yyyy-in-current-culture-info)

Comment: Ok, now I understand the question, and it is a good one, but very cryptic

Comment: I voted for close/deletion

Answer (score 2):

It does seem a little odd that the full option isn't available.  The closest I can suggest is to use custom formatting, but rather than supply your own, grab `DateTimeFormatInfo.LongDatePattern` and strip out any occurrence of "dddd" (and its surrounding space/punctuation).

That should give you the variation you want across cultures while removing the weekday.

---

Examples:

```
  en-US => dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy => MMMM dd, yyyy => November 22, 2018

  fr-FR => dddd d MMMM yyyy    => d MMMM yyyy   => 22 novembre 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand the solution for your problem could be to create a new `CultureInfo` object.

I've tested it.

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string usDate = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

CultureInfo fr = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
string frDate = fr.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

Console.WriteLine(usDate);
Console.WriteLine(frDate);

//Apply the country format here.
var localDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(frDate); 

Console.WriteLine(localDate);
```

So the format output will be as the location format you provide.

```
M/d/yyyy ---> USA format.
dd/MM/yyyy ---> France format.

22/11/2018 ---> France format applied to the current date.
```

For more information redirect to:
[CultureInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

$"{dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}"

This will show it as November 22, 2018 assuming that dt is assigned this date.
Also, check out [Custom Date Time Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please read the question carefully, I mentioned it has to take localization into account, I gave an example.

Comment: It seems like almost a correct answer for me, isn't it? It displays "[month] [day], [year]" in any current given culture, or any other culture, if specified as second parameter. Why "almost"? Because for Russian it says "ноября 22, 2018", which is gramatically incorrect.

Comment: My apologies, when i saw the question and answered things changed and I did not check to see if there had been any further entries before i posted.  This was my fault.

Comment: @Raarge Humility from the very start.  Gets my up-vote.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `LongDatePattern` from the current culture, then remove the day-of-week (`dddd`) and surrounding characters with a regular expression.  Below, I am assuming that commas, periods, and spaces are the only separators, but if you encounter others you may want to modify the regex accordingly.

```
string longDatePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
string modifiedDatePattern = Regex.Replace(longDatePattern, @"[,.]?\s?d{4}[,.]?\s?", "");

Console.WriteLine(longDatePattern);      //  "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"
Console.WriteLine(modifiedDatePattern);  //  "MMMM d, yyyy"
```

Now you have a custom format you can apply:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(modifiedDatePattern);

Console.WriteLine(s);  // "November 22, 2018"
```